# Locating a weak_ptr after shared_ptr is expired

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I have a struct, `A`, objects of which are managed by `shared_ptr`s. Struct `A` holds a reference to struct `B`. `B` objects need to keep track of which `A` objects hold references to them, and also need to be able to return `shared_ptr`s to these objects. To make this easy, I'm storing a set of `weak_ptr`s to associated `A` objects inside of `B`. So far, so good.

My problem is that I want `A`'s destructor to remove the reference to itself from its associcated `B` object. However, (what I thought was) the obvious solution doesn't work, as by the time `A`'s destructor is called, its associated `weak_ptr`s are expired, making it difficult to delete from the set. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

struct A;
struct B;

struct B{
   std::set<std::weak_ptr<A>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<A>>> set_of_a;
};

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>{
   B &b;
   A(B &b):b(b){};
   ~A(){
      // bad_weak_ptr exception here
      b.set_of_a.erase(shared_from_this());
   }
};


int main(){
   B b;
   std::shared_ptr<A> a1 = std::make_shared<A>(b);
   b.set_of_a.insert(a1);
   {
      std::shared_ptr<A> a2 = std::make_shared<A>(b);
      b.set_of_a.insert(a2);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this? I could just have `A`'s destructor run through B's set and erase any expired weak_ptrs, but that doesn't seem clean. I could also just convert `B`'s set to raw `A` pointers, and use those raw pointers to access A's `shared_from_this()` when needed, but I can't help but think I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Depending on one's paradigm of ownership, I'm in the camp that objects ought not know that they are owned by shared pointers.  So I wouldn't have them `std::enable_shared_from_this` because then they are self-aware they are `shared_ptr` owned.  (I may be flexible if they only have static factory functions to create them, and no public constructors otherwise.)

Comment: "I could just have A's destructor run through B's set and erase any expired weak_ptrs" isn't a bad approach, but it will be a lot cleaner if the code doing that is in a member function of B that A's destructor calls.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah, I agree `std::enable_shared_from_this` is abstraction-breaking; unfortunately I feel that way pretty often when dealing with smart pointers.

Comment: `std::set` requires that its elements don't change sort ordering while in the container. And a `std::weak_ptr` can change its correct sort ordering as a side effect of destroying a related `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: I don't understand the question - the whole point of `weak_ptr` is that you *don't* need to worry about them when the pointed-to object is destroyed.

Comment: @aschepler i thought it tracked the control block, not the owned object, and thus would not change?

Comment: @Caleth Seems you're right. But the Standard isn't very clear about it.

Comment: @Caleth When the weak pointer is seen expired, what prevents an implementation from decreasing the ref count and eventually releasing the control block?

Comment: @curiousguy the standard specifies that it doesn't release the control block until all the `weak_ptr`s are gone. The *whole point* of a `weak_ptr` is having defined behaviour for a "dangling" pointer situation

Comment: @Caleth "_the standard specifies that it doesn't release the control block until all the weak_ptrs are gone_" Where is that described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned the compiler - if you are on a new enough compiler, then you could use [weak_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this) (available from C++17):

```
b.set_of_a.erase(weak_from_this());
```

This would actually achieve what you want in a clean way since then you would just be comparing the actual `weak_ptr` instances instead of trying to create a new shared instance in the dtor, which logically fails now. Seems to work on coliru, but did not work on VS2017 (15.4.1) with C++17 enabled.

**Update for curiousguy**

This snippet:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;

struct B{
   std::set<std::weak_ptr<A>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<A>>> set_of_a;
};

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>{
   B &b;
   A(B &b):b(b){};
   ~A(){
      b.set_of_a.erase(weak_from_this());
      std::cout << "Size of set_of_a: " << b.set_of_a.size() << "\n";
   }
};


int main(){
   B b;
   std::shared_ptr<A> a1 = std::make_shared<A>(b);
   b.set_of_a.insert(a1);
   {
      std::shared_ptr<A> a2 = std::make_shared<A>(b);
      b.set_of_a.insert(a2);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

gives output:

```
Size of set_of_a: 1
Size of set_of_a: 0
```

on coliru (gcc 8).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck on -std=c++11, however it looks like I can do the same thing by giving each A object a weak_ptr to itself after the shared_ptr is created. It isn't pretty but seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, that is another way:) I basically just put this here in case of C++17.

Comment: @curiousguy - well the issue with OPs sample is, as mentioned in the accepted answer, that he is trying to construct a new shared instance in the dtor, which is not possible since the underlying weak_ptr is already expired. By using weak_from_this he can obtain the already expired weak_ptr from the object, and use it for lookup in the set.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Have you tested it? Which implementation supports that?

Comment: @curiousguy I tested it on coliru, seems that coliru is using gcc 8 now, so at least that works for sure:) I don't know about gcc 7, I don't have a setup to test on.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother eagerly erasing elements from `B::set_of_a`. When you `lock` the `weak_ptr` to access the object, check if it is null, and erase then.

You can't `shared_from_this` after `~A` has started, the `A` has ceased to be.

Comment: Good point about restrictions inside `~A`. The last thing you want is undefined behavior that appears to work today but stops working tomorrow.

Comment: Why waste resources?

Comment: @curiousguy it's a trade off between implementation complexity, time and space